# How can I reduce this code?

Tags: unity, c#

Could you help me to reduce this code as much as possible?

```
public GameObject[] TextPage;

public void Skin0()
{
    foreach (GameObject go in TextPage)
    {
        go.SetActive(false);
    }
    TextPage[0].SetActive(true);
}
public void Skin1()
{
    foreach (GameObject go in TextPage)
    {
        go.SetActive(false);
    }
    TextPage[1].SetActive(true);
}
public void Skin2()
{
    foreach (GameObject go in TextPage)
    {
        go.SetActive(false);
    }
    TextPage[2].SetActive(true);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than use a separate method for each entry that you might activate, pass the index of the entry you want to activate:

```
public void ActivateSkin(int index)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < TextPage.Length; i++)
        TextPage[i].SetActive(i == index);
}
```

This will iterate over the entire `TexpPage` array. For each entry, its position is compared to `index`. 
If the position is the same (that is to say, if `i == index` evaluates to true), then `SetActive()` will be set to true & if it is not, it will be set to false.

Comment: You posted basically the same code I had drafted, so I ditched my answer & added my explainer text to yours. Edit it as needed.

Comment: Sorry to steal your thunder!